# In grunt , how to exclude .git folder from clean in dist folder

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Currently my code is:

```
clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git/**'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
```

But it is still deleting .git folder in dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignoring the *.git* in *src* array should avoid deleting it.
The following task works for me (*before* section):

```
clean: {
        before: {
            src: ['dist/**/*', '!dist/.git/**', '!dist/.gitignore', 'temp'] //do not clean the git folder
        },
        after: {
            src: ['temp']
        }
    },
```

The *clean* task above clears the entire contents of the *dist* and *temp* folders except for what's inside *dist/.git* folder and the *dist/.gitignore* file.

I use this task as part of the build and deployment flow and it works fine, I keep my commits after each build&deploy although the *dist* folder is cleaned (without .git's).

Hope this helps someone!